# Is it possible to play Terraria mulitplayer online?

Tags: terraria

Does the game Terraria have a dedicated online server (like MMO games) that will save my progress? Or will I have to connect to other people like FPS games? Or can I do both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your character persists between worlds and is stored on your local machine as are single player worlds.  You can configure it to save to a different location (Dropbox etc).  Multiplayer worlds are saved in different places depending on the configuration of the server.

The term "dedicated" can mean two things here.  There is dedicated hosting which means some other place hosts the server software (usually for a price). There is also the dedicated server software which is separate from the Terraria client and allows anyone to host a server.

Comment: So to be sure you didn't make a typo; the character I use online is saved to my machine? Isn't that bad (people trading saves, etc)?

Comment: Yes, they are saved in My Documents/My Games/Terraria/Players. People can trade saves, but that takes all the fun out of the game.

Comment: You said "trade", so is there no way to "duplicate" someone else's work?

Comment: @Nobody - It's an expression. It shouldn't be too hard to duplicate save files.

Comment: You can copy someone else's character.  It doesn't have to be an exchange of saves.

Comment: I would buy the game if I could basically login to a multiplayer session without finding a server to connect to. This hasn't really been clear enough for me tbh.

Comment: There is a server list at http://www.terrariaonline-servers.com/

Comment: prob not going to buy then, lol

Comment: @nobody You do realise that it's a single player game, and why would you want to connect to a random server? You'd never be able to return to the stuff you did.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need [TerrariaServer.exe](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Server)
This is dedicated server program. This means that it doesn't have game GUI and only function of it to serve full functional game clients.
univ
Save files will be created locally, on machine where server is created. Of course, you can transfer files between game servers if you need.

> dedicated online server (like MMO games)

I don't know about existence of universal centralized Terraria server. It is unnecessary.

Comment: You don't *need* a dedicated server, but you can set one up. The alternative is selecting 'host game' from the main menu.